# How can I use vhosts with the same port in kubernetes pod?

Tags: port, load-balancing, kubernetes

I have an existing web application with frontend and a backend which runs on the same port (HTTPS/443) on different sub domains. Do I really need a load balancer in my pod to handle all incoming web traffic or does Kubernetes has something already build in, which I missed so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encurage getting familiar with the concept of Ingress and IngressController http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/

Simplifying things a bit, you can look at ingress as a sort of vhost/path service router/revproxy.